# Displaying object of arrays using angular keyvalue pipe in material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an object coming from response which looks like

```
{
    NET_TIME: [
        {
            createdBy: 'Alex',
            from: '9.0',
            to: '8.0'
        },
        {
            createdBy: 'Bob',
            from: '3.75',
            to: '4.03'
        },
        {
            createdBy: 'Carl',
            from: '5.13',
            to: '4.90'
        }
    ],
    OVER_TIME: [
        {
            createdBy: 'Jeffry',
            from: '0.3',
            to: '0.6'
        },
        {
            createdBy: 'Sam',
            from: '3.25',
            to: '4.01'
        },
    ],
    REMAINING: [
        {
            createdBy: 'Ron',
            from: '1.3',
            to: '1.5'
        },
        {
            createdBy: 'Alex',
            from: '9.8',
            to: '9.4'
        },
        {
            createdBy: 'John',
            from: '2.4',
            to: '2.6'
        },
        {
            createdBy: 'Paul',
            from: '3.4',
            to: '4.6'
        },
    ]
}
```

Now I want to generate 3 material tables from this, one for `NET_TIME`, one for `OVER_TIME` and one for `REMAINING`.

Columns will be same for every table, data will change.

I know how to achieve the same by getting the response into component, separating it by object keys and their values and defining 3 tables and giving values to it.

Just want to achieve the same using `keyvalue` pipe with `*ngFor` just in case if properties like `NET_TIME`, `OVER_TIME` are dynamic, I mean not fixed and I don't know how many will come.

Comment: You don't really need `keyvalue` here. Why exactly do you want to use it?

Comment: If I want to iterate over object using *ngFor, I have to use `keyvalue` pipe with *ngFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use ngFor with keyvalue pipe to get the data array for each key

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tableData of dataSource | keyvalue">
 {{ tableData.key }} , {{tableData.value | json }} 

</ng-container>
```

*now we will use value for dataSource*

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tableData of dataSource | keyvalue">
    <h4>
        <label for="">{{tableData.key }}</label>
</h4>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableData.value" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="createdBy">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.createdBy}} </td>
  </ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="from">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> from </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.from}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="to">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> to </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.to}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<br>

</ng-container>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymztps)

Answer (score 1):

You can try these .
You can get result any dynamic property in these syntax

```
<div *ngFor="let p of objectName | keyvalue">
  <div *ngFor="let q of p.value | keyvalue">
    <div *ngFor="let r of q.value | keyvalue">
        {{r.key}} {{r.value}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```